# How can i implement delete contact using TLSharp

Tags: c#, telegram

How I could detele contact list using TLSharp?

I tried this :

```
TLRequestDeleteContact req = new TLRequestDeleteContact
            {
                id = new TLInputUser
                {
                    user_id = //USER ID
                }
            };

            TLRequestDeleteContact updates = await _client.SendRequestAsync<TLRequestDeleteContact>(req);
```

but I have this error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLLink' to type 'TeleSharp.TL.Contacts.TLRequestDeleteContact'.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to cast the RESPONSE to TLRequestDeleteContact!
So, just use:

```
var updates = await client.SendRequestAsync<object>(req);
```

That's it.